# Finding Cos of an angle between matrices

Tags: matrices, intuition, inner-products

I have two  $2\times 2$ matrices and it's asking me to find the Cos of the angle between them. Firstly, how do yall visulize matrices and the angles between them? I think that's my first problem. Secondly, how can I visualize the inner product between 2 matrices? And lastly, I learned that the dot product is the standard inner product, how can I intuitively understand the inner product defined by $<A,B> = \mathrm{tr}(B^T A)$? That is, defined by transpose of $B$ multiplied by $A$?

Comment: It may depend what kind of "intuition" you're looking for. The inner product and angle between $2\times 2$ matrices is computed a lot like the same things for $\mathbb{R}$ (and someone has already pointed that out in an answer), but a visualization that has something to do with a geometric property of $2\times 2$ matrices _as matrices_ will be harder to come by.

Comment: I guess I want to know how, if this isn't in some kind of geometric space, how an angle can exist.

Comment: That was supposed to be $\mathbb{R}^4$ in my earlier comment. But it looks like the posted answer (not mine) was helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha$ is the angle between the matrices then you are asked to compute

$$\cos \alpha=\displaystyle \frac{\langle A,B\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle A,A\rangle}\sqrt{\langle B,B\rangle}}=\frac{\mathrm{tr}(B^TA)}{\sqrt{\mathrm{tr}(A^TA)}\sqrt{\mathrm{tr}(B^TB)}}.$$

This vectors (matrices) live in a four-dimensional space, which makes difficult to visualize some geometric quantities. But with that inner product you can identify your space with $\mathbb{R}^4$ with the following orthonomal basis $e_1=(1,0,0,0),e_2=(0,1,0,0),e_3=(0,0,1,0),e_4=(0,0,0,1)$ (that is, every vector has length one and any two of them are perpendicular).

The mentioned identification is as follows:

$$\left(\matrix{1 \: 0\\ 0 \:  0}\right)\rightarrow e_1, \left(\matrix{0 \: 1\\ 0 \:  0}\right)\rightarrow e_2, \left(\matrix{0 \: 0\\ 1 \:  0}\right)\rightarrow e_3, \left(\matrix{0 \: 0\\ 0 \:  1}\right)\rightarrow e_4 $$

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding how these matrices are making up a 4 dimensional space when each column of the matrice only has 2 components. I must not be understanding matrices correctly

Comment: You are right that each *column* of the matrix can be thought of as a two-dimensional vector.  But the *whole* matrix can be thought of as a 4-dimensional vector.  Just write the four components of the matrix out as a single list -- it doesn't really matter what order you use, as long as you are consistent.

Comment: Ahhhh! And that's why the standard basis has for components. Each element of the matrix is like a dimension then? That makes sense. When I was learning in the beginning of the course, I was taught to look at something like a 2 by 2 matrix as linear combinations of the column vectors. And now, when dealing with matrices are a whole, they are making up some kind of 4 dimensional space.

Comment: What's potentially confusing here is that the matrices have an obvious application to a two-dimensional space (they are linear transformations that preserve the origin), but this seems to have little to do with the angles we're computing here. For example, $\langle I_2, I_2 \rangle = 2$, so the matrix $I_2$ has magnitude $\sqrt{2}$ under this dot product. (This is a correction to a calculation error in my previously-posted comment.)